# Does Jensen's inequality become stricter with respect to the right boundary point?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, convex-analysis, conditional-probability, integral-inequality

Let $f(x)>0$ for all $t\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
$ be a density.  I will truncate the density to the finite interval $[a,b]$ and will eventually be taking a derivative with respect to the boundary point $b$.

$g$ is a positive, strictly increasing and convex function defined on the reals, and thus the expectation of $g$ is greater than $g$ of the expectation:

$$
\frac{\int_{a}^{b}g(t)\text{ }f(t)\text{ }dt}{\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\text{ }dt}%
-g\left( \frac{\int_{a}^{b}t\text{ }f(t)\text{ }dt}{\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\text{ }%
dt}\right) \geq 0
$$

(Jensen's difference)

**Question**: does this difference increase with respect to $b$ ?

Intuitively, as we expand the domain to the right we are including more of the even faster growing parts of $g$ so that the answers seems to be yes.

When I take the derivative of each term with respect to $b$, cancel and rearrange I find that the answer is "yes", if and only if $$\frac{g(b)-E\left[ g(t)\mid a\leq t\leq b\right] }{b-E\left[ t\mid a\leq
t\leq b\right] }\geq g^{\prime }\left( E\left[ t\mid a\leq t\leq b\right]
\right) $$

Looking at a proof of Jensen's inequality using a supporting line almost helps here, but not quite. This is where I am stuck.

Is the difference increasing?  Or is there a condition on $f$ such that it is?